# Specify version in "Assembly manifest" of private side by side assembly (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2005

I am creating a private side by side assembly and need to generate an Assembly manifest for that `dll`. The problem is that I don't know how I can specify a version to this manifest. (The version of `dll`/build is `#defined` in a header file)

I need to generate a manifest file like the one shown below. Present I uses a static manifest file with below content and specify it in `project settings->Manifest Tool->Input and output->Additional Manifest Files`. The only problem with this approach is that, I can't change the version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="MyCompany.MyDll" version="1.0.0.0"
                    processorArchitecture="x86" ></assemblyIdentity>  
</assembly>
```

Please advice, what is the correct procedure to create assembly file for private side by side dll.

Comment: Check the MSDN library article for the linker's /MANIFESTDEPENDENCY option.  Note the usage of #pragma comment in that article to inject this linker option in your source code.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear.

The client applications which uses my above dll, uses #pragma comment to add dependency to above dll. What I need is to create a manifest file, for private assemblies ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375674(v=vs.85).aspx )